# Apache Proxypass does work in a root folder, does not work in a subfolder

Tags: linux, apache, proxy, mod-proxy, proxypass

I have a Debian 10 with Apache and a special app with it's own webserver running at port 8181.
I made the setup as easy as possible for testing - no SSL etc.

It works well if I Proxypass to the root folder

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
Proxypass / http://127.0.0.1:8181/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8181/
```

I open example.com, it switches from example.com to app's login screen at example.com/login/login.html .But if I want it in a subfolder

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
Proxypass /test http://127.0.0.1:8181/
ProxyPassReverse /test http://127.0.0.1:8181/
```

I can still see the login page with the same URL example.com/login/login.html, but without pictures and after I click anything I get "Not Found" error.

I tried it in Nginx too and it does the same thing. I don't know if the app may have some kind of a redirect somehow interfering with the subfolder structure? I can't modify the app in any way. What am I missing here?

Comment: Could you please add `slash(i.e Proxypass /test/ http://127.0.0.1:8181/)` after test and let me know result.

Comment: yes, after adding the slash I get "404 Not Found" when trying to open example.com/test. When I try to open example.com/test/, I get 404 Not Found too, but the URL in address bar changes to example.com/login/login.html